# Problem calculating range from a populated array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, range

I'm currently doing an assignment for my access course in computing. Below I've  screenshot the project for contexts. Our teacher gave us coding snippets to get us started. In this case, he gave us code that populates 2 arrays from a user. I've written code that finds the smallest number in the array (to calculate the range) and it works. As shown below...

Context: https://i.stack.imgur.com/in3xz.png

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] values = {81, 52, 10, 50, 18, 4, 7};
    double smallest = values[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = values[i];

        }
    }
    System.out.println(smallest);
}
```

However, when I implement this code to my project, the result is always 0. I believe the problem lies with the snippet code. The function that finds the highest number works within the project. Finding the highest number and subjecting the smallest number works, however the smallest number result is always 0. I've pasted the whole program below. Sorry if it's too much work to fix, do you have any advice? Thanks

```
public static String[] strings;
public static double[] data;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    populatArrays();
    printArrays(strings, data);
    double theAverage = calculateAverage(data);
    System.out.println("The average rainfall is " + theAverage);
    double largest = getLargest(data);
    System.out.println("The largest amount of rainfall is " + largest);
    double smallest = getSmallest(data);
    System.out.println("The smallest amount of rainfall is " + smallest);
    double theRange = getRange(data);
    System.out.println("The rainfall range is " + theRange);
    double theTotal = getTotal(data);
    System.out.println("The total rainfall is " + theTotal);
}

//User input for the array & printing out questions
public static void populatArrays() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many cities would you like to add to the Rainfall calculator?");
    int elements = input.nextInt();
    String[] someStrings = new String[elements];
    double[] someData = new double[elements];

    for (int i = 0; i < someData.length; i++) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a City");
        someStrings[i] = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the annual rainfall");
        someData[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    strings = someStrings;
    data = someData;
}

//code printing out the array on screen
public static void printArrays(String[] stringArray, double[] doubleArray) {

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("City: " + stringArray[i]);
        System.out.println(doubleArray[i] + "mm");

    }
}

//code calculating the mean average
public static double calculateAverage(double[] thenumbers) {

    double sum = 0;
    for (double thenumber : thenumbers) {
        sum += thenumber;
    }

    double result = sum / thenumbers.length;
    return result;

}

//code calculating the largest number in the array
public static double getLargest(double[] thenumbers) {

    double largest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < thenumbers.length; i++) {
        if (thenumbers[i] > largest) {
            largest = thenumbers[i];
        }
    }

    return largest;
}

//code calculating the smallest number in the array
public static double getSmallest(double[] thenumbers) {

    double smallest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < thenumbers.length; i++) {
        if (thenumbers[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = thenumbers[i];
        }
    }

    return smallest;
}

// code calculating the range
public static double getRange(double[] thenumbers) {

    double largest = getLargest(data);
    double smallest = getSmallest(data);

    double theRange = largest + smallest;

    return theRange;

}

// code calculating the total rainfall in the array
public static double getTotal(double[] thenumbers) {

    double sum = 0;
    for (double thenumber : thenumbers) {
        sum += thenumber;
    }
    double theTotal = sum;
    return theTotal;

}
```

}

Comment: Such a long question and with external references... You will get more people helping you if you make the question as accurate and short as possible. Also, rewritting your question like this, you will see your problem with fresh eyes and maybe solve it yourself

Comment: If the thenumbers is not empty,try this `double smallest = thenumbers[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the initial value of smallest to 0

Since none of the data is less than 0, smallest is never getting set to another number.

Instead of setting the value to zero, I would suggest doing the same as in your original snippet and set it to the first value of the array

```
double smallest = thenumbers[0];
```

You are also doing the same in your getLargest function so if the highest number in your list is negative it will return 0.

As an added bonus you can condense your code a bit too using the for in/each operator `:`

```
//code calculating the smallest number in the array
public static double getSmallest(double[] thenumbers) {

  double smallest = thenumbers[0];

  for (double num : thenumbers) {
    if (num < smallest) {
      smallest = num;
    }
  }

  return smallest;
}
```

Comment: to check the length of thenumber to avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: You should never get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with for(var : collection). If you mean for setting the initial value, it seems OP knows he will always have an initialized array.

Comment: Thankyou so much!!

Comment: No prob :) I think knowing which situations MAX_VALUE and MIN_VALUE should be used is also very useful. Take a look at gnomed's answer. He covers it well.

Answer (score 1):

You should not initialize with 
`double smallest = 0;`

This means that unless you have a negative number in your array then this comparison will never succeed.

`if (thenumbers[i] < smallest)`

What you should do is initialize with

`double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE`

This means that your conditional will pass at least once when comparing to any other number in the array. Another option is to initialize it with an arbitrary number from the array (the first number for example).

`double smallest = thenumbers[0]`

Then continue the loop from there, you could change your loop to

`for (int i = 1; i < thenumbers.length; i++) {`

to skip the useless comparison of the first value against itself.

This assumes you have at least one value in the array which is not always a safe assumption but probably okay for a trivial example problem like this.